# Proof of a basic lemma about general topology.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Let $\emptyset \neq\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open. Then, show that there is a sequence of compact sets $\{K_j\}_{j=1}^\infty\subset \Omega$ s.t.
$$K_j\subset \mathring{K_{j+1}}\quad\mathrm{and}\quad \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \mathring{K_j}=\Omega.$$
($\mathring S$ denotes the internal of $S$.)

The proof says, "$K_j:=\{x\in\Omega\mid |x|\leqq j, d(x,\Omega^c)\geqq 1/j\}$ works."

I know that each $K_j$ is compact, $K_j\subset \mathring{K_{j+1}}\ $, and $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \mathring{K_j}\subset\Omega.$

I have to show $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \mathring{K_j}\supset\Omega.$

So, let $x\in\Omega.$

Then, there is $j_0\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $|x|<j_0.$

If I find $j_1\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $d(x,\Omega^c)>1/j_1$, then $j:=\max\{j_0,j_1\}$ will work. However, I cannot see the reason for the existence of such $j_1.$

If $\Omega^c$ is compact, then I know $d(x,\Omega^c)>0$ and such $j_1$ exists from Archimedean Property, but $\Omega^c$ is now not necessarily compact : $\Omega^c$ is only closed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Since $x \in \Omega$ and $\Omega$ is an open set, there exists a radius $r>0$ such that the ball centered at $x$ is contained in $\Omega$. Now consider $j_1 >1/r$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By contradiction, assume that there exists $x \in \Omega$ such that $x \notin \bigcup_{j} \overset{\circ}K_j$. Then, for all $j \in \mathbb N^*$, either $|x| \geq j$ or $\mathrm d(x, \Omega^{c}) \leq \frac 1j$. Hence, every $j \in \mathbb N^*$ such that $j > |x|$ verifies that $\mathrm d(x, \Omega^{c}) \leq \frac 1j$. Letting $j \to +\infty$, it results that $\mathrm d(x, \Omega^{c}) = 0$. Since $\Omega$ is an open set, $x \in \Omega^c$.

(this is not actually a proof by contradiction, I prooved that $\bigcap_j (\overset{\circ}K_j)^c =\left( \bigcup_{j} \overset{\circ}K_j \right)^c \subset \Omega^c$, but I find it easier to understand this way )